# How to formulate a correct statistical model for daily repeated measurements in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have performed an experiment on trees which were equiped with sensors to continuously measure their diameter. From this measurements I can define data for growth per day and maximum daily shrinkage (plants' diameters shrink during the day, isn't that cool). I have extracted this data for the following experimental set-up. Trees were divided in 2 greenhouses. One greenhouse had elevated CO2 and temperaturez (to simulate climate change) and the other was just ambient conditions. In each greenhouse half of the trees were water-stressed and the others were well-watered. This adds up to four treatments. For each treatment three trees were equiped with the sensors and were measured for 90 consecutive days.

I am interested in how the Temperature-CO2 treatment and water treatment (= fixed effects) influences the daily growth and maximum daily shrinkage.
As i see it I have repeated measurements with 2 fixed effects (2 treatments) and 2 random effects, being the 3 trees and the 90 measurements days.

Important in this case is that measurements are to be compared on a daily basis, because not only the treatment will have its effect but also external effects (such as the amount of sunlight). I am not per se interested in quantifying the effects of these external factors (as this will complicate matters too much).

I am working in R and my first shot was as follows:

```
    lmeGPD<-lme(growth_per_day~watertreatment*CO2treatment,
random=list(DOY=~1,tree=~1),data=summarytable)
```

`DOY` stands for Day of Year and is just the measurement day as a factor.

The main thing I am struggling with is that measurements should be grouped per day as external effects may have a greater effect than the treatment but I also think that over days measurements should still be grouped per tree as there is a certain degree of biological variation. Although I am not sure that the latter is true, as maybe this is just the factor that gives me multiple measurements.

But to be honest I am really not sure whether the outcome of this makes any sense and I wanted to ask whether this is indeed the way to go or should be changed.

Comment: So you have 3 trees per treatment combination, i.e. in total 12 trees? And 90 measurements per tree?

Comment: Yes, that is correctly.